# typescript import d3 and d3-force-attract

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I installed D3, and d3-force-attract

```
npm install @types/d3 -S
npm install -S d3-force-attract
```

Trying to figure out how import d3 force attract in as it is not a typescript module, but d3 is.

This is wrong

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3 from  'd3-force-attract';
```

Gives the following errors

```
src/Program.ts(4,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'd3'.
src/Program.ts(4,22): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'd3-force-attract'. '/.../node_modules/d3-force-attract/dist/d3-force-attract.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';//all modules will be in d3
```

the above line is fine,but line below you store all the modules from `d3-force-attract` into d3 which is wrong(you have assigned it above)

```
import * as d3 from  'd3-force-attract';
```

Instead do:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3force from  'd3-force-attract';//give it someother name like d3force.
```

*On another note*

I would suggest you not to import the full module, but selectively import the module you wish.

**example:**

`import { forceAttract } from 'd3-force-attract'`

This only imports `forceAttract` from `'d3-force-attract'` so if you building via webpack, it shall import only forceAttract into the minified build.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the types d3-force?

```
npm install --save @types/d3-force
```